# How do I walk through an object's keys in a consistent order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a js object that looks something like this:

```
var obj = {
  '1001' : [...data...],      
  '1002' : [...data...],      
  '1003' : [...data...],
  '1004' : [...data...],
  '1005' : [...data...],
  '1006' : [...data...],
}
```

And when I do this:

```
for (var i in obj) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

I get unpredictable order in Firefox. In other words, for most browsers I get the following logged to console:

```
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
1006
```

But Firefox does something more like this:

```
1006
1003
1001
1002
1005
1004
```

**How can I walk through the object's arrays and know for sure that I am getting them in the right order.**

Also to make it more complicated the keys might not be in sequential order and might not all be integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Object keys have no defined order. You'd have to explicitly `sort`:

```
Object
  .keys(obj)
  .sort()
  .forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(key);
  });
```

Comment: Yes but the last line of my Q says: "Also to make it more complicated the keys might not be in sequential order and might not all be integers."

Comment: What do you consider the "right order?" If they are supposed to be in a specific order, use an `Array`, not an `Object`.

Comment: I like your solution, the best answer is to use a different structure for the data. Unfortunately lots of work has been done using this structure and only Firefox messes it all up in the browser. The keys are an important part of the data. :(

Comment: Firefox is not necessarily storing anything in code order, so any ordering information is lost. Nothing to do there, really, short of changing the way the data is structured.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate it respecting insertion order you could use a `Map` instead of an Object.

```
var m = new Map();
m.set(1001, ..);
m.set(1002, ..);

for(var [key, val] of m){
   //iteration in order of insertion
}
```

Comment: Okay. My obj actually comes in as JSON. Is there a way to import a Map via JSON?

Comment: Well... If you'd write your own parser... otherwise it's still converted to an object and it's unordered.

Comment: @Octopus, actually I wouldn't even try to make a parser for that. If you get an object through JSON and you absolutely need an ordered list, I'd definitely reconsider a different data structure. All parsers will treat that as an unordered collection.

Comment: I agree writing a parser isn't the way to go, but apparently of all modern browsers, Firefox is the only one that does not honour the order. I wouldn't say that for objects in general, just the JSON parser.